# Google Sheets Arrayformula Calculating Very Slow

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas

I made a Google Sheet to track some metrics at my job. In a simple explanation, I create annotations (or tracks) on images and submit it for review. If it is reviewed and sent back to me, I fix it and add whatever I missed and send it back.

In order to track my progress, I wanted to create a formula that tracks how many total tracks I missed for each task (most recent attempt - earliest attempt). It took some finagling, but I finally got a formula that works. My only complaint is that it works extremely slow. Here is my formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Number of Tracks Missed"; IF(NOT(ISBLANK($F$2:$F)), IF($G$2:$G = 1, 0, (VLOOKUP($F$2:$F,SORT($B$2:$C, $A$2:$A, FALSE), 2, FALSE)) - (VLOOKUP($F$2:$F, $B$2:$C, 2, FALSE))), "")})
```

Column G is a count of how many times I have worked on a task, so if I've only had it once, then I didn't miss anything so that equates to 0. If it's been more than once, I use a complicated VLOOKUP combined with a SORT that flips the list of my tasks to the reverse order, so the VLOOKUP will find the most recent attempt, then subtract my earliest attempt from it.

Like I said, this formula works and gives the correct response every time, it's just super slow. Is there a way I can speed this calculation up, or is this the best/only option I have? I'm somewhat new to using formulas like this, so any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Thanks to player0 for pointing me in the right direction. My formula was fine, the problem was all the extra rows I had in the sheet. For some reason, There were 32,000+ rows. With the Arrayformula calculating for every single one, even if it's just with blanks, it was taking a long time.

As soon as I deleted the extras, it now calculates almost immediately.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eCSwQMXiZvUcc4X3GSb03649_5KASgQrPG3i7CRZSUw/edit?usp=sharing
Here's a copy of it. The formula in question is populating Column H

Comment: do you need to have 32k of rows in your sheet? is your dataset that large?

Comment: I never even noticed that. I never added any rows to it, my borders stop at row 1000. I deleted the extra rows and it calculates immediately. I'll amend my post to reflect this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somewhere along the path of creation of your sheet an error occurred and added 32k of empty rows to the sheet which caused you that decreased response.

if you don't need so many rows - delete them. your formula is fine.

Comment: Note for future visitors: be careful about the unbounded range being put into ARRAYFORMULA. The input range should have more rows than the output range. If the ARRAYFORMULA lives in row 2 (e.g. cell B2) make sure the input range starts from row 2. So, A2:A instead of A:A. Otherwise the sheet might continuously add new empty rows.